# Assign caps-lock to change input sources AND remove change input sources from globe key

Tags: macos, keyboard

My M1 MBP has this double function key, the <kbd>fn</kbd>/ key in the bottom left corner.

[image]

By default it, unfortunately for me, serves 2 purposes

1. It acts as the old <kbd>fn</kbd> key so pressing so for example <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>▶</kbd> = end, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>◀</kbd> = home, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>▲</kbd> = Page Up, <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>▼</kbd> = Page Down, etc...
2. If you have 2 or more input sources (eg, English + Japanese) then it switches between the sources

This has the frustrating experience that, for those unfortunately few people that actually use multiple input sources, in the normal course of using the <kbd>fn</kbd> combos above, quite often I end up switching input sources when I don't want to.

The solution I wanted to try to use was to turn off the  key's "change input source" function and change <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to instead be "change input source"

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do it.

Under System Preferences->Keyboard->Keyboard is the option to make the  key "Do nothing"

[image]

And under "Modifier keys" there is the option to set caps lock to be the  key

[image]

but unfortunately those 2 seem to in conflict. The first setting to make the  key "Do nothing" means that setting <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to  does nothing. Keeping  as "change input source" and setting <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to be  means caps lock changes input sources but the actual  key also still changes input sources.

Going over to Shortcuts->Input Sources and trying to "Select the previous input source" doesn't allow me to set it to <kbd>caps lock</kbd>.

[image]

Is there some other way I can make the <kbd>fn</kbd> key not change input sources and make <kbd>caps lock</kbd> change input source?

Comment: Isn't there a box to check to make Caps Lock switch keyboards in System Preferences > Keyboard > Input Sources?  This only works for switching between Latin and non-Latin keyboards, however, and it's not clear what you need.

Comment: I don't see the setting you mention [img](https://imgur.com/YtmqMbU). Also it's not an option under modifier keys either. [img](https://imgur.com/NWBS5Tk)

Comment: I don't think it is available with 3rd party keyboards like your Google stuff.  If you had Apple's Japanese IM on the list, you would probably see another box at the bottom for using Caps Lock.

Comment: Yes, the Apple Japanese IME has a caps-lock option. But it's irrelevant to the question above. All it does is switch modes inside the Japanese IME. It doesn't switch between input sources

Comment: That's not how mine works.  If US is the last Latin keyboard used, then caps lock switches Hiragana or Katakana to the US flag in the top right corner, so it is definitely switching input sources.  Only if you use Romaji last instead of US will caps lock switch to Romaji.  But that doesn't matter if you are using Google IM's anyway.  Google really should offer the caps lock option.  It's available when you make a custom layout for something like Russian in Ukulele.

Comment: I would argue Apple should fix this at a higher level rather than every individual IME have to add special options. The solution I was hoping for is that some MacOS guru would tell me which .plist to edit to set the keys the way I want that the SysPrefs has not provided a UI for.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question today and found that setting at:

```
Keyboard > Input Sources > Use the Caps Lock Key to...
```

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: It only works with Apple's keyboard layouts, and the OP is using one from Google instead.